# Making sure Ruby treats numbers as decimals rather than floats

Tags: ruby, type-conversion

Suppose I have a method like:

```
def calculate(alpha, beta)
  # do stuff
end
```

How do I make sure that when I call `calculate(1.0,2.0)` it will always treat the arguments as decimals and not as floats or integers?

Comment: Are you talking about the `Decimal` package?  It's been superseded by the `Flt` package.

Comment: I mean treat the types as `BigDecimal` type, which I believe is still supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for params to be handled as a BigDecimal, you can use the following:

```
    require 'bigdecimal'
    require 'bigdecimal/util'

    def calculate(alpha, beta)
      alpha_bigdec = alpha.to_d
      beta_bigdec = beta.to_d
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`BigDecimal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) class in the Ruby Standard Library

```
def calculate(alpha, beta)
  alpha = BigDecimal.new alpha
  beta = BigDecimal.new beta

  # rest of method here
end
```

You can then refer to the [BigDecimal documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to see which methods you can use to operate on it. A few I can think of off the top of my head are `to_s`, `to_i`, `to_r`, `add`, `sub`, etc.